Unity SharpDX IDirect3DSurface surface to SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D
I'm working on a UWP application in Unity with SharpDX and ffmpeginteropX, my goal is to be able to draw the frames from ffmpeg onto a texture within Unity. Currently I can draw to the Unity texture, and I can capture the frames from ffmpeg, but I cannot figure out how to combine the two. Previously I manually copied the frames via Unity but it was insanely slow copying from the GPU and CPU.
Here is how I have SharpDX and my texture set up:
// Class member variables
public UnityEngine.UI.RawImage target;
SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D m_DstTexture;
SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device device;
SharpDX.Direct3D11.DeviceContext deviceContext;

// Dummy texture hack to get device and context from Unity
UnityEngine.Texture2D targetX = new UnityEngine.Texture2D(512, 512, TextureFormat.BGRA32, false);
IntPtr texturePtr = targetX.GetNativeTexturePtr();
SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D dstTextureX = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D(texturePtr);

// Create DirectX device and context from texture
device = dstTextureX.Device;
deviceContext = device.ImmediateContext;

// Create shared texture for FFmpeg and Unity to access
SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2DDescription sharedTexture2DDescription = dstTextureX.Description;
sharedTexture2DDescription.OptionFlags = SharpDX.Direct3D11.ResourceOptionFlags.Shared;
m_DstTexture = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D(device, sharedTexture2DDescription);

// Get Shader Resource View to shared texture
var d3d11ShaderResourceView = new ShaderResourceView(device, m_DstTexture);

// Assign the shader resource view to the target RawImage
target.texture = UnityEngine.Texture2D.CreateExternalTexture(512, 512, TextureFormat.BGRA32, false, false, texturePtr);

FFmpeg setup:
// Member variables
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private MediaPlaybackItem mediaPlaybackItem;
private FFmpegMediaSource ffmpegMediaSource;
private SoftwareBitmap frameServerDest = new SoftwareBitmap(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, 512, 512, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied );
private UnityEngine.Texture2D tex;
private CanvasDevice canvasDevice;
private IDirect3DSurface surface;

private async void InitializeMediaPlayer()
{
    try
    {
        FFmpegInteropLogging.SetDefaultLogProvider();

        MediaSourceConfig configuration = new MediaSourceConfig()
        {
            MaxVideoThreads = 8,
            SkipErrors = uint.MaxValue,
            ReadAheadBufferDuration = TimeSpan.Zero,
            FastSeek = true,
            VideoDecoderMode = VideoDecoderMode.ForceFFmpegSoftwareDecoder
        };
        Debug.Log("FFmpegInteropX configuration set up successfully.");

        // Sample stream source
        string uri = "https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/sintel/mp4/h264/720/Sintel_720_10s_1MB.mp4";
        //string uri = "udp://@192.168.10.1:11111";

        // Create FFmpegMediaSource from sample stream
        Debug.Log($"Attempting to create media source from URI: {uri}");
        ffmpegMediaSource = await FFmpegMediaSource.CreateFromUriAsync(uri, configuration);

        // Create MediaPlaybackItem from FFmpegMediaSource
        mediaPlaybackItem = ffmpegMediaSource.CreateMediaPlaybackItem();

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer
        {
            Source = mediaPlaybackItem,
            IsVideoFrameServerEnabled = true
        };

        mediaPlayer.VideoFrameAvailable += MediaPlayer_VideoFrameAvailable;
        mediaPlayer.Play();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.LogError($"Exception while setting up FFmpegInteropX: {ex.Message}");
    }
}

Event for handling frames, this is where conversion should happen
private async void MediaPlayer_VideoFrameAvailable(MediaPlayer sender, object args)
{
    try
    {
        // Here frame should be copied to target, however types are not the same
        // MediaPlayer returns frames as IDirect3DSurface
        sender.CopyFrameToVideoSurface(surface);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.LogError($"Exception during VideoFrameAvailable: {ex.Message}");
    }
}


IDirect3DDxgiInterfaceAccess can be queried from an ID3DSurface (a WinRT interface) to get access to interop lower-level interfaces https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.directx.direct3d11.idirect3dsurface From there you can get DXGI/D3D11 surfaces (IDXGISurface, 2D textures, etc.). Not sure how to integrate  with that SharpDX (relatively old, so it's probably not aware of IDirect3DDxgiInterfaceAccess, you'll have to declare it manually) and Unity.

I found some helper APIs for using WinRT and SharpDX together https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture-video#helper-wrapper-classes There is a method that specifically converts SharpDX texture to ID3DSurface internal static IDirect3DSurface CreateDirect3DSurfaceFromSharpDXTexture(SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D texture) however I cannot get this to work just yet. Copying the helper methods directly cannot be compiled, and modifying results in type conversion errors during runtime.

If you post a reproducing sample somewhere I can have a look, but I can only help of DirectX/DXGI and SharpDX, not Unity.
